# Unable to show dialog | Facebook Appinvites | IONIC 2

Tags: android, facebook, ionic2

I am working with **Facebook** AppInvites.

I need to send direct message/invitation from my app to my facebook friends.

I am trying this code -

```
  this.facebook.appInvite(
                {
                    url: "myapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789",
                    picture: ""
                }
            );
```

Error -

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot show dialog

[image]

Comment: you will have to show where that code is called... Also are you trying this in a device?

Comment: This code is called on btn click and yes i am doing it in device.

Answer (score 3):

this feature is not available anymore and will be depcreated in a few weeks, so better search for another solution.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

I am sorry for having no better answer for you. It seems like facebook do not want to provide app invitations anymore.